# .NET MVC - Pressing Enter key in textbox not submitting form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, submit

I have a very simple form like below.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ...
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Input);
    ...
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

Pressing Enter key in the text field doesn't submit the form. I'm wondering if there is a solution that doesn't involve any JavaScript. Because when I searched online, there are people annoyed by this "default" behavior of the textbox and want to disable Enter key...

Maybe it has something to do with the 'button' tag? I tried changing it to 'input' tag. But pressing Enter still doesn't work. The rendered HTML looks normal to me:

```
<form action="/[ControllerName]/[ActionName]/" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
    ...
    <input id="Input1" name="Input" type="text" value="" aria-required="true">
    ...
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: Is there any javascript or jquery currently on the page? It sounds like there could be an event listener attached to form submit and cancels the default behaviour.  If not, what does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: @haldo, thanks for asking! The page don't have any JS or jQuery on it.

Comment: But it works when you click the button?  Is it only when pressing `enter` key that it does not submit the form?

Comment: Do you have another form hidden somewhere in the DOM? The enter key should submit the first form it finds.

Comment: @haldo, yes, it works when I clicked the button.

Comment: @BrandonMcAlees, you are right, there is another hidden form for anti-forgery and token validation.

Answer (score 1):

The enter key will always submit the first HTML Form on the page. Make sure you don't have another form element hidden within your HTML.